# How to run both neo4j and flask webapplication from the same docker container

Tags: docker, flask, neo4j, dockerfile

I want to run a whole application from a single docker container, the application has three components.

1. neo4j database that, must be accessible via a localhost port say bolt port 7687
2. a flask application that must access the database and the results or output of the same available across a localhost port say 5000
3. a web application page index.html that acts as the front end of the flask application. this will access the flask application via 5000 port.

i need the first two coponents to run from the same container.
i got the flask application containorised but could not get both running.

> i use a neo4j-community version and #not a neo4j docker image. so inorder to run the same we must execute neo4j start from neo4j-community/bin file

the docker file is stated below

```
FROM python:3.7

VOLUME ./:app/
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app
RUN cd neo4j-community-3.5.3/bin/
CMD ["neo4j start"]
RUN cd ../../
RUN cd flask_jan_24/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["flask_jan_24/app_flask.py"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it to run in the same container? This does not go very well with [Docker's recommendations](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) of running one service per container. Why is something like `docker-compose` not suitable for you?

Comment: its coz they have such a peculiar request, i have run it with neo4j working in the host system. but they have specifically asked to run it in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you have actually started Neo4j in the RUN statement (which is part of the build process).

Actually you should have a shell script which must launch all the required services (like neo4j or anything else) in background and then at the end you should launch the actual flask application.

Comment: And agree with bellackn's comment - docker-compose is the right way to break an application and provide a business solution rather than combining all the applications in one single container.